# Delete call recording and call transcript without deleting voice call record in Service Cloud Voice

Tags: apex, service-cloud-console, service

We are using Service Cloud voice. We have a requirement to delete call recording and call transcript without deleting voice call record. From initial investigation, the findings are we cannot query call recording, call transcript records using SOQL. Looks like they are stored in Amazon. We are able to delete call recording and transcript in amazon. Call recording goes away from salesforce, but transcript still stays in salesforce even after deleting from amazon connect. Any help is appreciated if there is way to delete transcript using apex or other way where it gets deleted from both places once deleted ion amazon.

Best,
Shiva

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.voice_delete_data.htm&type=5

Each message is saved as a Conversation Entry in Salesforce. You need to find the id of those entries through some SOQL queries and delete them through Workbench.
Query 1. Find the Conversation ID

```
Select ID,ConversationId
FROM VoiceCall
Where id=[id of the Voice Call record]
```

Query 2. Find the id of all related Conversation Entries

```
Select ID,isdeleted
FROM ConversationEntry
Where ConversationId=[the conversation id you got from query 1]
```

Hope that's helpful, good luck.